# SQL Query for events that happend in a specific order

Tags: sql, vertica

I have the following table:

```
+--------+-------+------+--+
| Object | Event | Time |  |
+--------+-------+------+--+
| Obj1   | A     |    1 |  |
| Obj1   | B     |    3 |  |
| Obj2   | A     |    7 |  |
| Obj2   | B     |    4 |  |
+--------+-------+------+--+
```

My goal is to get all objects that both had the event A & B with the condition that A happened first (in time). So far I only came up with the query to find me all objects that had A & B without including the time:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Object 
FROM
    (SELECT * 
     FROM
         (SELECT * 
          FROM table
          INNER JOIN 
              (SELECT Object Obj 
               FROM table 
               WHERE event LIKE '%A%' AS temp_table) ON table.Object = temp_table.Obj) AS temp_final 
     WHERE event LIKE '%B%') AS temp2;
```

So the end result would be that I get a table that includes only:

```
Obj1
```

Since this is the only Object that fulfills all criteria.

The time column is a Date stamp in real life, but for simplicity I used integers.

Thanks you for the help

Comment: I am using Vertica. I am aware there are such functions such as LAG and LEAD, but I wanted to see if there is an universal approach. Plus I still don't 100% how to use LAG and LEAD for my case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only tracking two events that happened one after the other, than you can solve this with a single `JOIN`.

This will work regardless of the number of events `Obj1` has, as how you mentioned, you are only interested in `A` and `B` existing and being one after the other, respectively.

```
select distinct t1.object
from TABLE t1
    inner join TABLE t2 on t1.object = t2.object
        and t2.time > t1.time
        and t1.event = 'A'
        and t2.event = 'B'
```

Here is a sample of the result of the code:

```
declare @tbl table (obj varchar(10), event varchar(1), time int)

insert @tbl values ('Obj1', 'A', 1), ('Obj1', 'B', 3), ('Obj2', 'A', 7), ('Obj2', 'B', 4)

select distinct t1.obj
from @tbl t1
    inner join @tbl t2 on t1.obj = t2.obj
        and t2.time > t1.time
        and t1.event = 'A'
        and t2.event = 'B'
```

Comment: I am still trying to understand what is happening here, but this seems to work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a compact solution which should run across most RDBMS.  This solution does not assume that there are only two events, and should run for any number of events.

```
SELECT t1.Object
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Object, MIN(Time) AS Time
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Object
) t2
    ON t1.Object = t2.Object AND
       ((t1.Event = 'A' AND t1.Time = t2.Time) OR
        t1.Event <> 'A')
GROUP BY t1.Object
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2    -- change this count to match # of events
```

**Demo on MySQL:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Where do you define that the Object must have Event B?

Comment: The condition `t1.Event <> 'A'` will cover the other record being event `B`.  If the `COUNT` is 2, then it means it has `A` and `B`.  This will also work in case you have more than two events.

Comment: I don't understand, so if I have multiple events (e.g. A, B, C) and I only want the objects that only had events A & B in that order, how would this work?

Comment: It may not cover all cases.  But for example, if you wanted `A` first, as well as both `B` and `C` present, you'd only have to change the count to 3 and my query would work.  Anyway, it definitely works for your problem.

Comment: Did you bother to even try the demo I setup?

Comment: Yes I did, but it crashed on me after I started changing some values.
Like when changing the line
Obj2   | A     |    7 
to
Obj2   | A     |    3

Comment: @valenzio Fiddle is prone to breaking.  Just try the query directly in Vertica.

Comment: I first tried it in vertica, and it did not produce the right result. Now fiddle is working and I also can't get the query to work probaly when making changes to the tabel. I still can't see how it could work without mentioning condition B in the whole querry.

Comment: You don't need to mention `B` because not `A` means `B`

Comment: Yes that I understand, but If you have more events like 'A' , 'B' and 'C' than 'not A' means 'B' or 'C' , :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT object
FROM yourtable t
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT FROM yourtable t3
    WHERE t3.object = t.object
    AND t3.event = 'A'
    AND EXISTS
        (SELECT 'B'
        FROM yourtbale t4
        WHERE t4.object = t3.object
        AND t4.event = 'B'
        AND t4.time > t3.time)
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql-server:

```
SELECT
      A.[Object]
    , A.[Time]
    , B.[Time]
FROM
    (SELECT 
        Distinct [Object]
    FROM
        [table] AS A
    WHERE
        A.[Event] = 'A'
    ) AS A
        CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT
        TOP 1 *
    FROM
        [table] AS B
    WHERE
        [Event] = 'B'
        AND
        B.[Object] = A.[Object]
        AND
        A.[Time] < B.[Time]) AS B
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server:

```
;with A as
(select Object, MIN(Time) as Time from table where Event='A' group by Object)
, B as
(select Object, MIN(Time) aS Time from table where Event='B' group by Object)
Select A.Object from A inner join B on B.Object=A.Object where A.Time < B.Time
```